# the multi part identifier could not be bound in an update query

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-update, identifier

First of all I've looked at similar questions but failed to find one for my case.
The access code i am turning into sql is as follows (I didn't write it)

```
UPDATE QUpdateTrialstepApproved1 
INNER JOIN TrialStepApproved ON 
QUpdateTrialstepApproved1.cid_req = TrialStepApproved.cID 
SET TrialStepApproved.wm21 = [wm2_req], 
TrialStepApproved.sw = [startweek_req], 
TrialStepApproved.PlannedTotalm2 = [m2_req], 
TrialStepApproved.ew = [endweek_req], 
TrialStepApproved.ActualNrofDiffEntries = [entries_req],
TrialStepApproved.entryfactorTrial1 = [eFtrial_req],
TrialStepApproved.fixeddeliveryweek = [fixedEndweek_req],
TrialStepApproved.culturename = [culturename_req] 
WHERE (((QUpdateTrialstepApproved1.approveRequestChange)="v") 
AND ((TrialStepApproved.Location) Is Not Null));
```

I've turned it into the following but I get the error in the title:

```
UPDATE A  
SET B.wm21 = [wm2_req], 
B.sw = [startweek_req], 
B.PlannedTotalm2 = [m2_req], 
B.ew = [endweek_req], 
B.ActualNrofDiffEntries = [entries_req], 
B.entryfactorTrial1 = [eFtrial_req], 
B.fixeddeliveryweek = [fixedEndweek_req], 
B.culturename = [culturename_req]
from QUpdateTrialstepApproved1 as A 
INNER JOIN TrialStepApproved as B ON A.cid_req = B.cID 
WHERE A.approveRequestChange='v' AND B.Location Is Not Null
```

Comment: you can;t update A and then have the set part of the query use the other table on the left side of the = . Try swapping teh left and right.

Comment: Exactly what i thought but to my confusion it works in access :)
What do you mean swap left and right?

Comment: You are updating table A but setting table B fields? also what DBMS are you using?

Comment: I am using Sql server 2005
and it is working in access that's why i didn't know if i should change it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're updating `B`, not `A`. Change the first line to

```
UPDATE B
```

...and thing will work fine.

[An SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3bbda/1).

Comment: That's what i thought but won't that change the meaning?
In the original access code it is updating A but setting the values in B
If i change the A to B it will update the wrong table, wouldn't it?

Comment: @AngelicCore Access will allow updates of the second table in a join, you can switch the table names around in the access query without changing anything. In both cases, you're updating `TrialStepApproved`.

Comment: Sweet I didn't know that. :)